# Combining plots created with cowplot::ggdraw() with patchwork: consistently formatted tags?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, patchwork

I am trying to combine a plot generated with `ggplot` with jpeg images using `patchwork`. Here is my current code:

```r
# load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# generate and save dummy jpeg
jpeg::writeJPEG(matrix(.5, nrow = 533, ncol = 800), "test.jpg")

# read dummy jpeg
test_jpeg <- jpeg::readJPEG("test.jpg", native = TRUE)

# use ggdraw from cowplot to plot the image
plot_1 <- cowplot::ggdraw() + cowplot::draw_image(test_jpeg)

# get dummy plot
plot_2 <- ggplot2::ggplot() +
    geom_blank() +
    theme(aspect.ratio = 4/3)

# combine with patchwork
plot_combined <- (plot_2 + plot_1 )/plot_1  +
  plot_layout(heights = c(1, 1)) +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A') 

# save to png
ggsave(filename = "plot_combined.png",
       plot = plot_combined,
       width = 4,
       height = 4)
```

This results in the following output:

[image]

This has the following problems:

- Tags are differently formatted. Tags for the panels containing the images are bold. [Edit: solved]
- Tags are not horizontally aligned. [Edit: solved]
- Heights are not identical for all panels.

I am looking for solutions to solve these problems.

### Edit

I solved the different formatting by setting `theme(plot.tag = element_text(face = 'plain')`

I tried using `background_image()` from `ggpubr` to create the image panel.

Further, I try to specify the layout of the plot generated with `patchwork` specifically using the `area` function:

```r
# use background_image() from ggpubr to plot the image
plot_1 <- ggplot() + ggpubr::background_image(test_jpeg) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 2/3)

# get layout for plotting
layout <- c(
  area(t = 1, l = 1, b = 4, r = 3),
  area(t = 1, l = 4, b = 4, r = 9),
  area(t = 5, l = 1, b = 8, r = 6)
)

# combine with patchwork
plot_combined <- plot_2 + plot_1 + plot_1  +
  plot_layout(design = layout, heights = 1) +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A') +
  theme(plot.tag = element_text(face = 'plain'))

# save to png
ggsave(filename = "plot_combined_2.png",
       plot = plot_combined,
       width = 4,
       height = 4)
```

Resulting in the following:

[image]

Problems with this are:

- Panel heights are still not identical.
- The offset between panels and tags is not identical for the upper and lower row.

Comment: I solved the different formatting by setting `theme(plot.tag = element_text(face = 'plain')`.